# How to send email in Windows command prompt using only pipes (no files) with newlines?

Tags: windows, email, command-line, newline

I want to send email using only pipes without writing the message to a temporary file in Windows XP command prompt. I can do it with for example blat.exe, but I can't get the newlines to work.

I tried this kind of command:

```
echo something something & echo.more of something | blat.exe - -to my.email.address@domain.com
```

But this just sends "more of something" and ignores the everything before the last newline (& echo.).

Comment: Why the restriction to pipelines? (Eg. could variables be used?) Also does this have to be `cmd.exe`? (Much easier in PowerShell.)

Answer (score 1):

This is doing:

```
echo something something & (echo.more of something | blat.exe - -to my.email.address@domain.com)
```

What you actually want is:

```
(echo something something & echo.more of something) | blat.exe - -to my.email.address@domain.com
```